# android current time will not working properly

Tags: android

In my case just display current time in textview but it not working properly.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = calendar.getTime();

dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String todayAsString = dateFormatter.format(today);
datePickUp.setText(todayAsString);

SimpleDateFormat dF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
String currentTime = dF.format(today);
timePick.setText(currentTime);
```

In `today` the value is **Wed Jun 21 12:22:32 GMT+05:30 2017**
but in `currenTime` value is as **06:52 AM**.

Comment: Are you using a emulator? have you tried the same code in Real device? have you checked the device time?

Comment: I am using my own android device. Yes, I checked the time. It is current time

Comment: your code works ok!

Comment: Sorry guys, I have import wrong packages.Now working thank you all

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [android text time format](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html)

```
import java.util.Calendar
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

or those who might rather prefer a customized format, you can use:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```